# How to unmount a disk mounted using "mount" and not hdiutil or diskutil?

Tags: macos, mount

I wanted to try to mount a Linux ISO in Mac and later mount it in a docker container (all for learning) but I wasn't able to mount the disk using hdiutil command as it kept on giving error -

```
$hdiutil mount rhel-server-7.4-x86_64-dvd.iso
hdiutil: mount failed - no mountable file systems
```

So I found a workaround [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298685/can-a-mac-mount-a-debian-install-cd/298785#298785) and I was able to successfully mount the disk at mount point in /tmp

Output of mount command:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk5 on /private/tmp/rhel-installer (cd9660, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, mounted by username)
```

Output of diskutil list command:

```
$diskutil list
/dev/disk5 (disk image):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +4.1 GB     disk5
1:                       0xEF                         9.2 MB     disk5s2
```

How do I unmount this ISO mounted at /tmp/rhel-installer?

I have used diskutil unmountDisk command which runs successfully but doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried `umount`?

Comment: @PoisonNinja yeah. Its say command not found :(

Comment: `/sbin/umount` should be there. Which system are you using?